# verify that an OS package is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, capistrano

I need to verify that an OS package is installed after deploying using capistrano (it's a rails project, in case it matters). I'd like to support the major linux distros and OS X. Fortunately, the name of the package is the same on all platforms.

I've thought adding a capistrano task, something like (untested code):

```
%w(yum apt-get brew).each do |manager|
  path = `which #{manager}`.chomp
  if path && path.size > 0
    `#{path} install -y #{PKG}`
    return
  end
end
```

Inspired by [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46081/52730).

Is there a better way?
I've thought checking `uname`, but it doesn't always have the distro, just "Linux". I also thought using `lsb_release` or listing files in `/etc/*-release`, but not all distros support it (e.g. centos).

Comment: You need to take into account the fact that each package manager has its own syntax / options for checking that a package is installed or not.

Comment: Yes, but luckily the `install` command is idempotent on all managers.